# I can access my pod and service endpoint but not ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I am having trouble accessing my k8s api through its ingress controller. Using port-forward to my pod IP ClusterIP service, I can verify that the api is accessible. However, when trying to access through the ingress setup, the IP address is not accessible. How do I debug it?

My Deployment is setup as follows:

```js
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: weather-api
  labels:
    app: webapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-weather
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-weather
        api: weather
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: xyz/weatherforecast:v2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
```

Service:

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8100
      targetPort: 80
      name: web
  selector:
    app: ingress-weather
  type: ClusterIP
```

And ingress controller:

```js
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: app
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service: 
              name: api-svc
              port: 
                number: 8100
```

Using either of the following port-forwards, allows me to access my api through //localhost:8080/:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/weather-api-99c9c7fd6-7sr6z 8080:80
kubectl port-forward service/api-svc 8080:8100
```

kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx returns:

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.240.185   104.42.145.179   80:32294/TCP,443:31047/TCP   4d2h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.116.19    <none>           443/TCP                      4d2h
```

But when I access //104.42.145.179:32294/api it does not resolve (times out).

what else can I do to find the cause of no access?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have mentioned the **32294** you access it directly.

Try something like, as you have now ingress controller with port **80** & **443**

http://104.42.145.179/api

also, make sure your ingress controller POD is running

**Update**

Looks like you ingress is in **wrong** **namespace** : **namespace: app**

while your **port-forward** is from the **default** namespace

```
kubectl port-forward service/api-svc 8080:8100
```

So when the request comes to ingress it finds the **service** in **app** namespace

Remove the **namespace** from ingress and try

Comment: Thank you. What does the 32294 signify then? Internal port to which 80 is mapped? I tried your suggestion with same result - times out. As I mentioned the pod is running OK - I used port-forward to hit its endpoint from my machine and got correct result.

Comment: updated answer check once..! that is node port which map to LB svc but since we are using the LB and expose the 80 we can use that only with ingress.

Comment: I used *kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=app* before doing port-forward - that's why it worked. I removed namespace: app from my ingress.yaml and still same timeout. after removing it, *kubectl get pod --n app* returns the one and only running pod. While *kubectl get ingress --n default* returns the ingress. My plan was to keep my apis in a particular namespace. I am happy to remove all ns refereneces from the lot to see whether that works then but would be nice to be able to do the partitioning.

Comment: sorry was not aware you have default NS set, anything in logs of nginx controller ? please do set the ingress in which service is available. check logs of controller once

Comment: Yes, ingress has a log entry 'Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/api-svc": no object matching key "default/api-svc" in local store'. So how do I tell my ingress controller, which is in one ns (ingress-inginx) to map some paths to a service in a different namespace (app/api-svc)?

Comment: Change ingress namespace in which service exist and check logs again remove from default

Comment: Ingress' log now shows: "GET /api/weatherforecast HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "... [app-api-svc-8100] [] 10.244.1.3:80 0 0.001 404 ...". kubectl get svc api-svc shows its cluster ip as 10.0.49.255. 10.244.1.3 is the IP of the pod running my api (per kubectl describe pod).

Comment: It’s 404 path not found in service or that type error based on logs